# Ansi SQL riddle

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I have a table (in Oracle 12, but I would like to use only ANSI sql) defined and populated like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (GROOM VARCHAR2(50), BRIDE VARCHAR2(50), STATE VARCHAR2(50));

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('ALVIN','CARMEN','NJ');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('ALVIN','CARMEN','VA');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('ALVIN','ELEANOR','NJ');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('CARL','CARMEN','AL');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('CARL','ELEANOR','AL');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('DAVID','DIANA','NE');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('FRANK','DIANA','NV');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('MIKE',NULL,'RI');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (GROOM,BRIDE,STATE) VALUES ('MIKE',NULL,'WI');
```

I would like to get a result with this criteria:

- for each groom (from the alphabetical lowest name), take the "not already married" bride with the alphabetical lowest name, and with the alphabetical lowest State (if bride is the same). If no bride is available, then set her to NULL.

For example: the lowest groom is Alvin, which can be married to Carmen (in NJ and VA) or Eleanor. The result is:

```
Alvin, Carmen, NJ
```

Now the lowest is Carl, which can be married to Carmen (but she is already married with Alvin) or Eleanor. So the result is:

```
Carl, Eleanor, AL
```

So at the end I would like to get this result set:

```
Alvin, Carmen, NJ  
Carl, Eleanor, AL  
David, Diana, NE  
Frank, NULL, NV  
Mike, NULL, RI
```

As I said, I would like to use only ANSI SQL (so the fact that I'm using Oracle is not relevant), no temporary table, cursors or table self joins. 
Window functions are OK.

Thanks

Comment: Why does your table start with brides and grooms already linked by being in the same row in the table - shouldn't they be separate to start with, with grooms in one table and bride/state in another? What does being in the same row currently indicate; and are there three people called Alvin, or just one?

Comment: My table is indeed a result set from a very complex query. There are no separate tables such as BRIDES or GROOMS. Alvin is just one.

Comment: That makes no sense, how do we know that and how do we know where Alvin lives?

Comment: "State means" where they can get married.

Comment: Why can't Alvin marry Carmen in AL? You can only pick the first bride from those linked to the groom? The 'not already married' part didn't suggest that (to me anyway).

Comment: @AlexPoole Because groom, bride and state must all be in the same row as I understand it. I guess it is like a variant of an arranged marriage

Comment: Yes Joakim, you are right. Consider that the real case is made of numbers (and some 'obscure relations' between them) instead of grooms and brides.

Comment: You need a recursive query for this. Why is is NV for Frank? Frank has no match, so can't it be any state? I would have expected NULL accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all it would be good if you can explain the nature of the restrictions.

For example, it may be reasonable when someone wants to implement the logic in pure SQL but what is the point to ban self joins? Also, do you consider correlated sub-queries from the same table as self joins? What about scalar sub-queries?

Looks like you want to do some trick with analytic (also known as window) functions but that is not possible because in this specific case because you need to track which brides have been reserved so far and analytic functions do not have any kind of state.

There are two typical approaches for tasks like yours (when you "iterate" through rows and maintain some "state") in Oracle

- recursive sub-query factoring (also knows as recursive CTEs)
- model clause

Let me start with model, even though it's very specific Oracle feature

```
SQL> with t as
  2  (
  3    select *
  4    from mytable
  5    model
  6      dimension by (groom, bride, state)
  7      measures (0 reserved)
  8      (
  9        reserved[any,any,any] order by groom, bride, state
 10        = case
 11            -- current groom already has a bride
 12            when max(reserved)[cv(groom), lnnvl(bride > cv(bride)), any] = 1
 13            -- current bride already reserved for some groom
 14            or max(reserved)[groom < cv(groom), cv(bride), any] = 1
 15            then 0 else 1
 16          end
 17      )
 18  )
 19  select groom, bride, state
 20    from t
 21   where reserved = 1
 22   union all
 23  select groom, null, min(state)
 24    from mytable
 25   where groom not in (select groom from t where reserved = 1)
 26   group by groom
 27   order by 1;

GROOM      BRIDE      STATE
---------- ---------- ----------
ALVIN      CARMEN     NJ
CARL       ELEANOR    AL
DAVID      DIANA      NE
FRANK                 NV
MIKE                  RI
```

In this solution column `reserved` is used to mark each row where bride is "allocated". Approach works only in Oracle starting with version 10g Release 1 when model clause has been initially introduced.

Second solution is below

```
SQL> with rec(groom, bride, state, reserved)
  2       as (select min(groom),
  3                  min(bride) keep (dense_rank first order by groom),
  4                  min(state) keep (dense_rank first order by groom, bride),
  5                  min(bride) keep (dense_rank first order by groom)
  6             from mytable
  7           union all
  8           select t.groom,
  9                  t.bride,
 10                  t.state,
 11                  r.reserved || '#' || t.bride
 12             from rec r
 13             cross apply
 14              (select min(groom) groom,
 15                      min(bride) keep (dense_rank first order by groom) bride,
 16                      min(state) keep (dense_rank first order by groom, bride) state
 17                 from mytable
 18                where groom > r.groom and instr(r.reserved, bride) = 0) t
 19            where t.groom is not null)
 20             cycle groom set c to 1 default 0
 21  select groom, bride, state
 22    from rec
 23   union all
 24  select groom, null, min(state)
 25    from mytable
 26   where groom not in (select groom from rec)
 27   group by groom
 28   order by 1;

GROOM      BRIDE      STATE
---------- ---------- ----------
ALVIN      CARMEN     NJ
CARL       ELEANOR    AL
DAVID      DIANA      NE
FRANK                 NV
MIKE                  RI
```

In this solution you can get rid of specific Oracle feature `keep dense_rank` and avoid using `cross apply` which was introduced only in 12c. Also you can keep track of reserved brides using collection instead of concatenated string but... again this is Oracle specific solution.

However, this one (with minor modifications) can be adopted to, say, SQL server.

**PS.**

Speaking about performance, recursive solution scans entire mytable during each execution of recursive member which makes it nonviable on any relatively big dataset.

`model` may be fine on, say, thousands of rows but still it calculates aggregates (`max(reserved)`) for each row which can be avoided in non-SQL approach.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This project has several db targets (also embedded ones), that's why Ansi Sql is important. Performance is very important too, datasets may be quite large and recursion and self joins can be a problem.

Comment: @user1630809: A recursive query is the only way to solve the problem properly in SQL, because this is an iterative process. The only other option is not to do this in SQL, but with a programming language instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some tests with the following query.
I'm not sure about it, so please do not consider it as a proposed solution (if you find some conceptual or de facto mistakes, it would be really very appreciated).

The idea is to identify an ordered list of groom and brides (via window functions), then to change the name of a bride if her rank is superior to the coupled groom one, in order to subsequently exclude her grouping by groom and using a min operator.

```
SELECT GROOM
/*oracle specific string functions, every system has its own equivalent*/
, REPLACE(SUBSTR(COMPOUND, 1, INSTR(COMPOUND, ';', 1, 1) -1), 'ZZZZZZZZZZ', NULL) AS BRIDE 
, SUBSTR(COMPOUND, INSTR(COMPOUND, ';', -1, 1) +1) AS STATE
FROM
(
    SELECT GROOM
    , MIN(CASE WHEN RANK_GROOM < RANK_BRIDE AND RANK_BRIDE <> 1 THEN 'ZZZZZZZZZZ' 
ELSE BRIDE END || ';' || STATE) AS COMPOUND
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        GROOM, COALESCE(BRIDE, 'ZZZZZZZZZZ') AS BRIDE, STATE
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GROOM ORDER BY BRIDE, STATE) AS RANK_GROOM
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BRIDE ORDER BY GROOM, STATE) AS RANK_BRIDE
        FROM MYTABLE
    ) T1 
    GROUP BY GROOM
) T2
```

p.s. The use of the name 'ZZZZZZZZZZ' is obviously not 'elegant', but in my real case I'm working with numbers, so it can be considered as the replacement for a max numeric constant value.

Edit: I made many tests during these days and it seems that the above query fits all my needs.